# Golang profiler cannot find source code

Tags: go, profiling

I've included the `net/http/pprof` package in my code. I can then comfortably run the `pprof` profiler (on Debian):

```
go tool pprof http://localhost:9000/debug/pprof/profile
```

Commands such as `top10` or even generating call graphs work as expected. However, as soon as I try to go into a function, it fails:

```
(pprof) list MyFunc
No source information for mypkg.MyFunc
```

My `GOPATH` is set to my project's directory. Do I need any special flags or environment variables while building my source code or while running pprof?

Comment: Can you add  your code

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. That is my question. How can I let `pprof` know about my code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the answer with the help of the golang-nuts people. I needed to specify the binary:

```
go tool pprof mybinary http://localhost:9000/debug/pprof/profile
```

This way the source code is found and can be listed with the "list" command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `"net/http/pprof"`, albeit on windows. 
Using `"runtime/pprof"` instead, with `pprof.StartCPUProfile / StopCPUProfile` solved it.